# How to work with alertmanager alerts one by one

Tags: slack, prometheus-alertmanager

In alertmanager config for slack examples i may typically see something like:

```
text: >-
     {{ range .Alerts -}}
     {{ .Annotations.text }}
     {{ end }}
```

but this glues all of notification in a single pule of junk, and not processing them one by one, so each message is a separate slack notification. How can I send as many slack messages, as there are Alerts?

also each message should go to its own channel, defined in alert's annotation, is something like this possible?:

```
slack_configs:
  - channel: '{{takeMeOneAlert}}{.Annotations.slackChannel}}{{end}}'
```

range just glues strings from different alerts into 1 big pile of crap, and i want them to be processed separately

Comment: Can you share the `routes` section of AlertManager configurations?

Comment: @aclowkay issue is solved by killing grouping in routes